# Adding elements to Django database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a large database of elements each of which has unique key.  Every so often (once a minute) I get a load more items which need to be added to the database but if they are duplicates of something already in the database they are discarded.

My question is - is it better to...:

1. Get Django to give me a list (or set) of all of the unique keys and then, before trying to add each new item, check if its key is in the list or,
2. have a try/except statement around the save call on the new item and reply on Django catching duplicates?

Cheers,
Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MySQL, you have the power of `INSERT IGNORE` at your finger tips and that would be the most performant solution. You can execute custom SQL queries using the cursor API directly. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

If you are using Postgres or some other data-store that *does not* support `INSERT IGNORE`  then things are going to be a bit more complicated.

In the case of Postgres, you can use rules to essentially make your own version of `INSERT IGNORE`.

It would look something like this:

```
CREATE RULE "insert_ignore" AS ON INSERT TO "some_table"
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM some_table WHERE pk=NEW.pk) DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

Whatever you do, avoid the "selecting all rows and checking first approach" as the worst-case performance is O(n) in Python and essentially short-circuits any performance advantage afforded by your database since the check is being performed on the app machine (and also eventually memory-bound).

The try/except approach is marginally better than the "select all rows" approach but it still requires constant hand-off to the app server to deal with each conflict, albeit much quicker. Better to make the database do the work.